# Ubuntu install DVD boots straight to trial with no install or try option and then the install button does nothing

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I used this DVD to load Ubuntu on to a laptop with Windows Vista and had no issues.

Now when I boot with the same DVD on another laptop with Windows 7 I get no try/install options just boots straight to trial. I have tried clicking Install once it has loaded the trial but nothing happens.

The laptop has an i7 CPU, 450GB HDD and 8GB RAM. I have created two spare partitions both are 60GB. One is formatted FAT32 and the other is unallocated. Can anyone help?

Sorry if this question has already been asked I did search without any luck prior to posting this question.

Comment: My end goal is a dual boot system.

I have 60gb unallocated so it will not be seen as in use.

When I click on the install ubuntu on the desktop nothing happens

Comment: I am sorry for being rude, but did you  read/understand the question.

Comment: You say reflash the usb.... I am using a dvd.

Comment: You say verify the dvd.... I did and have used this dvd to successfully install on another laptop